# How to fix the \tikz\width error and \tikz\height error?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, errors, width, height

I drew two graphs using tikz package.

However, there are errors about '\tikz\width' and '\tikz\height'.

How to fix those errors?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.47\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        width = \linewidth,
        height = \linewidth,
        compat=newest,
        ylabel = Y,
        xlabel = X,
        ymode = log,
        xmajorgrids = true,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        xmin = 100, xmax = 350,
        ymin = 1, ymax = 7,
        xtick = {100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350},
        ytick = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
        yticklabels = {$1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, $5$, $6$, $7$},
        every tick/.style={small}
        ]
        \addplot[
        scatter/classes={1={mark=*},2={mark=x}},
        scatter = true,
        scatter src = explicit symbolic,
        only marks,
        scatter,
        nodes near coords* = {\scriptsize\Label},
        visualization depends on = {value \thisrow{name} \as \Label},
        ] table [ x = {X}, y = {Y}, meta = class] {
            Y   X   class   name        
            1.216   133.9   1   A   
            6.176   217.8   1   B       
            2.048   329.6   2   C       
            1.536   278.2   2   D       
            1.408   316.9   2   E       
            1.256   341.2   1   F           
            1.721   167.8   1   G   
        };
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \label{fig:1}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill  
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.47\textwidth}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        width = \linewidth,
        height = \linewidth,
        compat=newest,
        ylabel = Y,
        xlabel = X,
        ymode = log,
        xmajorgrids = true,
        ymajorgrids = true,
        xmin = 200, xmax = 1200,
        ymin = 2, ymax = 17,
        xtick = {200, 400, 600, 800, 1000, 1200},
        ytick = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16},
        yticklabels = {$2$, $4$, $6$, $8$, $10$, $12$, $14$, $16$},
        every tick/.style={small}
        ]
        \addplot[
        scatter/classes={1={mark=*},2={mark=x}},
        scatter = true,
        scatter src = explicit symbolic,
        only marks,
        scatter,
        nodes near coords* = {\scriptsize\Label},
        visualization depends on = {value \thisrow{name} \as \Label},
        ] table [ x = {X}, y = {Y}, meta = class] {
            Y   X   class   name        
            2.400   231.5   1   A   
            16.448  737.3   1   B       
            4.032   673.5   2   C       
            3.136   656.0   2   D       
            2.784   934.8   2   E       
            2.480   1101.6  2   F           
            3.281   402.5   1   G   
        };
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \label{fig:2}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{CAPTION}
    \label{fig:SOME}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Try removing the `every tick/.style={small}`.  Not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish with that, but perhaps you meant `every tick/.style={thin}`.

Comment: @PeterGrill Yup, it tries to execute `/pgfplots/small/.style`, which is given by `{
                width=6.5cm,
                height=,
                tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
                label style={font=\small},
                max space between ticks=25,
        },`, but the problem is that it switches to the `/tikz` directory for the drawing options.